# gulp sass.logError not working in visual studio task runner

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, gulp-sass

Consider the following code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var gdebug = require('gulp-debug');

module.exports = function (sourcedir, targetDir, directTarget)
{
    return function ()
    {
        var source = directTarget != null ? directTarget : sourcedir + '/**/*.scss';

        return gulp.src(source, { base: sourcedir })
            .pipe(sass({ includePaths: [`${sourcedir}/**/`] }).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(targetDir))
            .pipe(gdebug());
    }
}
```

When running this in the visual studio task runner, all errors within the sass compilation are completely hidden. If I replace sass.logError with a simple `function(e){console.log(e)}`, the error event gets logged as expected.

I'm quite sure this worked as it should before, I just recently noticed that I had some scss-files that silently failed to compile. What could have happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alex,

We came across the exact same issue today and were looking for alternatives. Turns out the `sass.logError` function does not pass the error back into the `gulp` system but to the 'process.stderr.write(message + '\n');'

This is found in the `index.js` file under the path.

`\\Project\nodule_modules\gulp-saas\index.js\`

The function is defined on line 170 (apx) as.

```
//////////////////////////////
// Log errors nicely
//////////////////////////////
gulpSass.logError = function logError(error) {
  var message = new gutil.PluginError('sass', error.messageFormatted).toString();
  process.stderr.write(message + '\n');
  this.emit('end');
};
```

As a work around I have modified the file to print to the `gutil.log` method, which in turn passes to the Console in visual studio.

First you will need to enter a require entry at the top of the file (with the rest) as (this only makes pretty colors)

`var chalk = require('chalk');`

Then modified the logError as below.

```
//////////////////////////////
// Log errors nicely
//////////////////////////////
gulpSass.logError = function logError(error) {
  gutil.log('Error', chalk.red('Uncaught error while processing task ') + '\'' +  chalk.cyan('saas') + chalk.red('\'.'));
  gutil.log('Message', error.formatted);
  this.emit('end');
};
```

You will see that two lines are printed to the console, first line with a generic message (in red to catch your attention) followed by the message.
The object passed in `error` is a standard Javascript Object with the following properties.

```
{
    "formatted":
    "message":,
    "column":,
    "line":,
    "file":,
    "status":,
    "messageFormatted":,
    "stack":,
    "showProperties":,
    "plugin":
}
```

Here is an example result.

[image: example of gulp-error message in Visual Studio]

Comment: I can't do this, as I don't want to hack it for all the dev team, nor commit node_module hacks... Maybe gulp-sass team should fix it?

Comment: @TDaver and Nico, check my answer. Seems the culprit was Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this was due to a bug in [Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935). There is now a new version released, Preview 2, and this problem seems to be solved.

Hence no need for workarounds.